# Javascript modal window that zooms to and from a position when opening and closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQuery UI's dialog functionality for modal windows.  What I need now is for the window to zoom into existence from a particular location on the webpage.  And when closing the window, it needs to zoom over to that position as well (this part is more important).

Can I do this with jQuery UI's dialog?  Is there another javascript or jQuery library for modal dialog windows that will zoom down to a position on the webpage?

Comment: by zooming, what exactly do you mean? Something similar to http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html ?

Comment: @Niklas - exactly what I meant!  this is a legitimate answer, thanks.  Is there a way to get that kind of zooming functionality with jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the effect for `show`/`hide` with the default jQuery UI dialog like this:

```
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "scale",
            hide: "explode"
        });
```

You can preview the different transitions available [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/).

Perhaps the closest ones to what you are looking for are scale/puff/transfer, preview of them at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/xD8UT/).

If that doesn't satisfy what you are looking for, I would recommend going with the flowplayer option then. Example of a dialog window with the apple effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/D3ZJk/

Comment: Yes, the scale effect makes sense, but how do I make it scale from a particular DOM element (or position)?  Your example shows the window scaling from the center of the "screen".

Comment: You can set the position parameter, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/xD8UT/9/ but it will just assign the top-left position of the window, not where it is zoomed out of.

Comment: I see what you mean... that doesn't work though, I need to have that "apple effect" from flowplayer's overlay widget.

Comment: I would recommend going with the flowplayer option then, I've updated my answer with an example how you could use it.

Comment: I've got this working somewhat, I just don't know how to NOT have the element popup the overlay when you click on it.  Seems that is a requirement of flowplayer's Overlay widget...